# Apache mod_dbd didn't work correctly. 'Can't load driver file apr_dbd_mysql.so'

Tags: c++, c, apache

I found a Apache mod document in the page of https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/mod/mod_dbd.html.
When I tried to use it in apache module development,fisrtly I need to configure the file httpd.conf according to the document.Then,when I use  the command "httpd -t" to test the configuration I got this message 'Can't load driver file apr_dbd_mysql.so'. I found some effective solutions on Linux,but my Apache worked on Windows 10.how to solve this problem in Windows 10 simplely?

Apache 2.4.x OpenSSL 1.1.1 VS17
Download URL:https://www.apachehaus.com/cgi-bin/download.plx

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/mod/mod_dbd.html
I tried to cofigure the Apache mod_dbd for mysql,but it didn't work well.The Error Message is 'Can't load driver file apr_dbd_mysql.so'.

Comment: I don't think this is a programming question. Are you writing software for this? If not there are better stackexchange sites for this type of question. https://superuser.com/  https://unix.stackexchange.com/ https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apache

Comment: This may not be strictly a programming question, but I do want to make a gadget with the five apis provided on the page.  There were some problems above in the prepared stage, and the solutions I found were to recompile apr_util on Linux, but I was looking for the most detailed solution on Windows, not Linux. You can find those API on the documentpage given in my question.

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_dbd.html

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem from  following words.

Connecting to databases - DBD/M Suport

Apache Haus builds include three (3) DBD conectors, ODBC, MySQL and SQLite3. ODBC is included in Windows and SQLite3 is in the public domain so the required sqlite3.dll has been included in this package.

The MySQL connector requires (libmysql.dll) may be obtained from

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

Note that this MySQL conector was built against MySQL 5.6.21 (but earlier or later versioned 5.6 .dll's may work.) libmysql.dll must be included in Apache's /bin folder to use the connector.